# Big O notation comparison with constant time

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics

So,  I'm new to this whole asymptomatic notation with respect to algorithms. So say you have a $f(n) = 1/n$ and $g(n) = 1$,  would it be OK to say that $f(n)$ is not equal or is not an element of $O(g(n)) $?
 I say this because I'm actually drawing an analogy with another example.  Say in my second example $f(n) = n$ and $g(n) =n^2$ then I'm sure that $f(n)  = O(g(n))$.

Comment: Your second example is correct. How/why do you think the two are (not) analogous?

Comment: Just because a lot of times I find myself learning by previous examples.  But I also think that $f(n)$ is not equal because $O(1)$ is constant time

Comment: [Also related](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, $1/n = O(1)$. Recall the (simplified) definition of big O: for positive functions $f,g$, $f(n) = O(g(n))$ if there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that $f(n) \leq Cg(n)$ for all $n$. In your case, the constant $C = 1$ would do since $1/n \leq 1$ for all $n$.

The fact that $f(n) = O(g(n))$ just means that $g(n)$ is an *upper* bound on $f(n)$, i.e., that $g(n)$ grows at least as fast as $f(n)$. The two functions need not have the same order of growth.